# Unable to save pdf file into access database

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to update an existing record in the access db table and save a pdf file.
However, I'm getting "No value given for one or more parameters" error.

Please see the code below. Any help will be much appreciated.

Thanks

```
Dim strsql As String
Dim settings As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("ABCBO.My.MySettings.db_abcdealsConnectionString").ConnectionString
Dim con As New OleDbConnection
Private Sub printtopdf_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles printtopdf.Click
    con.ConnectionString = settings
    Try
        Dim fs As New FileStream("E:\NewApp\test1.pdf", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)
        strsql = "UPDATE ABC_DEALS SET CONFIRMATION_COPY = @AT1 WHERE DEAL_TICKET = '" & TextBox5.Text & "'"
        Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand(strsql, con)
        Dim byteArr(CInt(fs.Length)) As Byte
        fs.Read(byteArr, 0, fs.Length)
        fs.Close()
        con.Open()
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@AT1", OleDbType.Binary).Value = byteArr
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        con.Close()
    Catch exc As Exception
        MsgBox(exc.Message)
        con.Close()
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: Few things, first I think your syntax for the parameter is wrong.  From memory Access uses ? with positional parameters.  Next, you should also use parameters for your Where condition rather than string concatenation.  And finally, have a read on IDisposable, the Using clause and how that works with DB connection objects

Comment: @Hursey You are correct about OleDb and positional parameters but you can still use a name for readability. Just make sure that the order they are added to the parameters collection matches the order they appear in the sql statement.

Comment: Where does the value of byteArr come from?

Comment: You may want to consider storing a path to the .pdf in the database and put the file, itself, in a directory on the E drive. Saves having to convert the file to a Byte() and then rehydrating it on retrieval.

Comment: @Hursey I have used the same syntax for INSERT query with just '@C1' and there is no ?. I also changed the parameter for WHERE Condition to '@DT1' but still got the same error

Comment: @Mary here is the declaration for byteArr 'Dim byteArr(CInt(fs.Length)) As Byte'

Comment: I'm still stuck with this. Any help will be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`FileStream`, `OleDbConnection`, and `OleDbCommand` all have a `Dispose` method that needs to be called so unmanaged resources can be released. Vb.net provides `Using...End Using` blocks that will handle this for us and also close the connection and the stream. The `Using` block in the data access code includes both the connection and the command. Note the comma after the connection line.

You are trying to do too many things in the click method. Separate the data access code from the rest.

**Always** use parameters. User input like `TextBox5.Text` could introduce malicious code into your database. Parameter values are not considered executable code by the database.

Pass the connection string to the constructor of the connection.

Pass the `CommandText` and the `Connection` to the constructor of the command.

Don't open the connection until directly before the `Execute...`

Even if this doesn't solve the problem, it will offer you a clearer idea of where the problem is. Put in a break point and step through the code checking for variable values.

```
Private settings As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("ABCBO.My.MySettings.db_abcdealsConnectionString").ConnectionString

Private Sub printtopdf_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click 'printtopdf.Click
    Dim byteArr As Byte()
    Dim path As String = "E:\NewApp\test1.pdf"
    Try
        Using fs As New FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)
            ReDim byteArr(CInt(fs.Length))
            fs.Read(byteArr, 0, CInt(fs.Length))
        End Using
        Dim Updated = UpdateDatabase(byteArr, CInt(TextBox5.Text))
        MessageBox.Show($"{Updated} has been successfully updated.")
    Catch exc As Exception
        MsgBox(exc.Message)
    End Try
End Sub

Private Function UpdateDatabase(PDF As Byte(), Ticket As Integer) As Integer
    Dim strsql = "UPDATE ABC_DEALS SET CONFIRMATION_COPY = @AT1 WHERE DEAL_TICKET = @Ticket;"
    Dim RecordsUpdated As Integer
    Using con As New OleDbConnection(settings),
         cmd As New OleDbCommand(strsql, con)
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@AT1", OleDbType.Binary).Value = PDF
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Ticket", OleDbType.Integer).Value = Ticket
        con.Open()
        RecordsUpdated = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    End Using
    Return RecordsUpdated
End Function
```

**EDIT**

```
Private Function GetByteArrayFromFile(FilePath As String) As Byte()
    Dim file As Byte()
    Using stream As New FileStream(FilePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read),
            reader As New BinaryReader(stream)
        file = reader.ReadBytes(CInt(stream.Length))
    End Using
    Return file
End Function

Private Sub printtopdf_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click 'printtopdf.Click
    Dim path As String = "E:\NewApp\test1.pdf"
    Dim byteArr = GetByteArrayFromFile(path)
    Try
        Dim Updated = UpdateDatabase(byteArr, CInt(TextBox5.Text))
        MessageBox.Show($"{Updated} has been successfully updated.")
    Catch exc As Exception
        MsgBox(exc.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
```

**EDIT 2**

I see 3 places that the code needs to be changed to accomidate a Long. I have added a validation `TryParse` to the code to make sure the input is the correct type.

Old code 1

```
Dim Updated = UpdateDatabase(byteArr, CInt(TextBox5.Text))
```

New code 1

```
    Dim ticket As Long
    If Not Long.TryParse(TextBox5.Text, ticket) Then
        MessageBox.Show("Please enter a valid ticket number")
        Exit Sub
    End If
    Dim Updated = UpdateDatabase(byteArr, ticket)
```

Old code 2

```
Private Function UpdateDatabase(PDF As Byte(), Ticket As Integer) As Integer
```

New code 2 Note: The return type stays Integer.

```
Private Function UpdateDatabase(PDF As Byte(), Ticket As Long) As Integer
```

Old code 3

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Ticket", OleDbType.Integer).Value = Ticket
```

New code 3 It seems the the OleDbType.BigInt maps to Int64. In Access the field should be Number 8 bytes. Not positive of this. You may have to play with it a bit.

```
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Ticket", OleDbType.BigInt).Value = Ticket
```

**FINAL RECAP**

```
Private Sub printtopdf_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click 'printtopdf.Click
    Dim path As String = "E:\NewApp\test1.pdf"
    Dim byteArr = GetByteArrayFromFile(path)
    Try
        If String.IsNullOrEmpty(TextBox5.Text) Then
            MessageBox.Show("Please enter a valid ticket number")
            Exit Sub
        End If
        Dim Updated = UpdateDatabase(byteArr, TextBox5.Text)
        MessageBox.Show($"{Updated} has been successfully updated.")
    Catch exc As Exception
        MsgBox(exc.Message)
    End Try
End Sub

Private settings As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("ABCBO.My.MySettings.db_abcdealsConnectionString").ConnectionString

Private Function UpdateDatabase(PDF As Byte(), Ticket As String) As Integer
    Dim strsql = "UPDATE ABC_DEALS SET CONFIRMATION_COPY = @AT1 WHERE DEAL_TICKET = @Ticket;"
    Dim RecordsUpdated As Integer
    Using con As New OleDbConnection(settings),
            cmd As New OleDbCommand(strsql, con)
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@AT1", OleDbType.LongVarBinary).Value = PDF
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Ticket", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = Ticket
        con.Open()
        RecordsUpdated = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    End Using
    Return RecordsUpdated
End Function

Private Function GetByteArrayFromFile(FilePath As String) As Byte()
    Dim file As Byte()
    Using stream As New FileStream(FilePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read),
        reader As New BinaryReader(stream)
        file = reader.ReadBytes(CInt(stream.Length))
    End Using
    Return file
End Function
```

Comment: Many thanks for sharing the code. I tried this and got "Arithmetic Operation resulted in an overflow". Nevertheless, I will debug as you mentioned and try to make it work. Appreciate the support. Thanks.

Comment: sure. I have set the data type of the pdf field in the access database as "OLE Object". is this correct?

Comment: @ganeshsp Please correct my code to           `cmd.Parameters.Add("@AT1", OleDbType.LongVarBinary).Value = PDF`
  `LongVarBinary` maps to `OLE Object`.

Comment: Thanks. I marked yours as the most helpful answer; as it truly is. Actually, my deal number is 16 digits and integer data type is not helpful. I changed CInt to Clng for the TextBox5.Text and subsequently the data type for Ticket in UpdateDatabase function. Now I'm encountering a "Failed to convert parameter value from a Int64 to a Int32." error. Tried different combinations and google searches but no luck yet.

Comment: @ganeshsp Please see EDIT 2.

Comment: Now I'm getting no value given for one or more parameters. But when I debugged, both the variables carries values.

Comment: Have you checked your database for the datatypes of the parameters?  I know that OLEObjec maps to LongVarBinary. Can you check the datatype in the databse of the Ticket field?

Comment: I have set the datatype for Ticket field as Short Text as changing it to Long Number creates version compatibility issues

Comment: See FINAL RECAP in my answer.